# Using remote IP in pdo connection returning NULL for pdo connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a project and I have deployed it in my server with IP `192.168.1.5` When I access my project using `192.168.1.5/project` It runs OK When I tried to run my project in my localhost like `127.0.0.1/project` My PDO connection is null And I dont understand why. MY  connection is:

```
define('DBHOST', '192.168.1.5');// database host address - localhost is usually fine
define('DBNAME', 'dbname');// database name - must already exist
define('DBUSER', 'username');// database username - must already exist
define('DBPASS', 'password');
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST."", "".DBUSER."", "".DBPASS."", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci"));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbname = "`" . str_replace("`", "``", DBNAME) . "`";
    $dbh->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname");
    $dbh->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $dbh->query("use $dbname");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    echo "\n\n";
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

My connection goes to catch part and returns this error:

```
PDO::errorInfo():
Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object in
```

When I try to `var_dump($dbh)` I get `NULL`

Why is not working when I run localhost and when I run in remote server it does run..

> Reason Why I want to run in localhost:

Is so that I can do it faster. Right now I need to upload the changes in server to see the result. I want to run in localhost so I dont need to upload to see changes

Comment: define('DBHOST', '192.168.1.5');/ to define('DBHOST', 'localhost');/

Comment: Just get rid of the catch part

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez I want to use the database from my server and not from my local host that is why I used the IP of my server in that part